# What services do I have to restart to effect config changes in puppet.conf when using foreman?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppet-agent, puppet-foreman

I have puppet 3.8.4 installed via the latest foreman installer.

I enabled the $facts['fact_name'] hash by putting these lines in my puppet.conf:

```
trusted_node_data = true
trusted_server_facts = true
```

I restarted some services to try to affect the config change:

```
sudo systemctl restart foreman-proxy
sudo systemctl restart puppet
```

But $facts['fact_name'] declarations were still failing.

I completely restarted the server and it started working.

So my question is what services do I have to restart to effect config changes?

I see that with foreman installed (via the foreman installer) the puppetmaster service is disabled (which is why I didn't touch it):

```
● puppetmaster.service - Puppet master
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetmaster.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When I was using straight puppet I had this service enabled and running, but foreman didn't enable it (and foreman is working fine so I guess its supposed to be that way). Would starting and stopping this service affect config changes?

How does foreman work with services like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart Apache, via `systemctl restart httpd` or I think, `touch /etc/puppet/rack/tmp/restart.txt`.

Foreman's installer configures the Puppet master to run under Passenger and Apache (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/25-puppet.conf`), rather than using the standalone service. It scales and performs a lot better.